# Cast long from smaller byte array (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a byte array to long, but receive *BufferUnderflowException*

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    byte[] arg1 = new byte[] {0x04, (byte)0xB0};
    buffer.put(arg1, 0, arg1.length);
    buffer.flip();
    long val = buffer.getLong();
```

In debug mode, I looked inside buffer. It has an internal byte array, and it fills the unspecified bytes with "0". So why does the exception occur? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should use `Long.BYTES` to fill your `buffer`. If your `byte[]` is exhausted you could switch to 0. Like,

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
byte[] arg1 = new byte[] { 0x04, (byte) 0xB0 };
for (int i = 0; i < Long.BYTES; i++) {
    int pos = Long.BYTES - i - 1;
    byte val = (pos < arg1.length) ? arg1[pos] : 0;
    buffer.put(val);
}
buffer.flip();
long val = buffer.getLong();
System.out.println(val);
```

Output is

```
45060
```

Going the other way

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(45060));
b004
```

Comment: Thanks, Elliot. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 5):

The spec of `getLong()` specifically says that it throws `BufferUnderflowException` if `there are fewer than eight bytes remaining in this buffer`. Your buffer has only two bytes.

Comment: Thanks Eran. Do you know how to set rest of bytes to zero to avoid such exception?

Comment: @KostyaKrivomaz You can add 6 leading or trailing bytes (based on the result you expect to get) containing 0.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` may have an `Object[16]`, but that still doesn't mean that its logical size is bigger than the number of elements you've added. You need eight bytes in the buffer to read a `long` out of it.

If you are trying to use that byte array as an unsigned short, just write leading zero bytes to the buffer. Not sure why you want a long over an int if it's just two bytes, though.

Comment: 2 is just particular example, number of bytes can vary from 1 to 8

Comment: Then just subtract the number of bytes from 8 and write that many zeroes first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with -:
**buffer.flip();**

flip is used to flip the buffer from read to write mode or write to read mode by resetting the limit as the current position.

If you comment out the line, it will work fine.

Comment: Just try to comment flip - nothing has changed. But whatever, thanks for help)